# How to get the iterated item in findAll()

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

I'm working with Mikro-ORM and NEST.JS. I have Users, Games and Messages. I want to find all users and their games, and populate ONLY THOSE messages that are sent by the user.

In the find(id) function that can be easily done because in the parameter I have the user's id, so I can compare the message's user to the user.

*user.service.js:*

```js
async find(id: number) {
        return await this.userRepository.findOne(({
            id: id,
        }),{
            fields: ["name"],
            populate: ["games","games.messages"],
            populateWhere: {
                messages: {user: id}
            }
        })
    }
```

But in findAll() I don't have the iterated user, how could I specify the message's "user" field to be the current iterated user?

*user.service.js:*

```js
async findAll() {
        return this.userRepository.findAll({
            fields: ["name"],
            populate: ['games','games.messages','games.messages.game'],
            populateWhere: {
                messages: {
                    user: user.id  // <--- cannot find user.id
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PopulateHint.INFER`.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/loading-strategies#population-where-condition

---

And next time please dont use screenshots, I'd be happy to provide code snippet for that, but not if I can't even copy your version...

Comment: PopulateHint.INFER is just a constant, it has nothing to do with what I want to achieve.
I edited the post and made code snippets.